# Visiting Node in BFS and DFS in the same order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, trees, bipartite-graphs

if G be a connected, undirected graph and has at least 3 vertex. we know the order of visiting node from a given vertex in BFS and DFS is the same. which of the following is false?

a) G can be a complete graph.

b) diameter of G is at most 2.

c) G can be a complete bipartite graph.

d) G must be a Tree or Complete Graph.

Anyone could help me for any hint or tutorial...

Comment: At least, show what you've tried out so far!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/984133/14578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think there are 2 false statements in there.  I hope the following hints will help you.

EDIT : since OP has figured it out, I'll post the answers.

a) If $G$ is a complete graph, can you find an ordering of the vertices of $G$ that can not correspond to a DFS visiting order ?  Can you find one that can't be done by a BFS ?

EDIT : a) is TRUE.  Any vertex ordering can correspond to a visiting order of a BFS, or a DFS.  So having the same order is possible.

b) Say $G$ is a path of length 4  (so the diameter is greater than 2), and 
say this path is $a \rightarrow b\rightarrow c\rightarrow d$.  Do a BFS starting from $a$.  Do a DFS starting from $a$.

EDIT : b) is FALSE.  Both traversals will give the ordering $a,b,c,d$ when starting from $a$.

c) Look at a complete bipartite graph having one side with just a single vertex (a star tree).  What if this vertex is the first visited by BFS or DFS.

EDIT : c) is TRUE.  Both traversals can yield the same ordering when starting from the single vertex.  Though I believe star trees are the only bipartite complete graphs with this property.

d) Take a complete graph having at least 4 vertices, and remove a single edge $e$.  It's not a tree, nor a complete graph.  Start visiting from a vertex $v$ not incident to $e$.

EDIT : d) is FALSE.  Starting from $v$, all orderings of the other vertices are possible in both traversals.

Comment: Well, I'd rather wait until you've tried to figure it out yourself.  I can post the direct answers later on, but I believe the hints should be enough to guide you.  That is, assuming you understand the BFS/DFS algorithms.  Is the distinction between these two clear to you.

Comment: Great !  That's correct.

Comment: Sure !  Here it is.